# Font's not showing as they should on react/next app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fonts, google-fonts

I cannot get some fonts to show as they should be shown once importing them into my React app.

I am using Next.js and Chakra UI.

**Theme folder:**

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import '@fontsource/notable';
import '@fontsource/inter';

export const theme = extendTheme({
    fonts: {
      heading: `'Notable, sans-serif'`,
      body: `'Inter, sans-serif'`,
    },
```

**App:**

```
<Heading fontSize={'10rem'}>Heading</Heading>
```

**Screenshot of how it should look:**

[image]

**Screenshot of how it looks for me:**

[image]

Am I missing something really simple or does this font just not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide the code for your root App and your component?

Have you done this step, from: https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/using-fonts?

1. `npm install @fontsource/notable @fontsource/inter`
2. Import the fonts into a theme (you already did it above)
3. Then **import the relevant font weights and styles** into the theme file you created **OR** the same root file you import ChakraProvider into.

```
    import '@fontsource/notable/400.css' <---- this one
    import '@fontsource/inter/700.css'   <---- this one
    
    import {
      ChakraProvider,
      Heading,
    } from '@chakra-ui/react'
    import theme from './theme'
    
    const App = () => (
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        ...
        <Heading>The spectacle before us was indeed sublime.</Heading>
      </ChakraProvider>
    )
```